# Random Image URL From Google

Tags: php

I am wondering if someone knows how to get a random Image URL From Google in php ?

Comment: Do the google search and get the result in an array. pick a random element.

Comment: i don't mind what kind of photo just a random one everytime the page reloads

Comment: If it's for getting a random image in a mockup, you could look into using the API at https://random.dog/ (See https://github.com/AdenFlorian/random.dog)

Answer (score 0):

> First download and include [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), i hope it will be useful for someone.

```
<?php
require_once( "simplehtmldom.php" );

$image  = random_image( "life" );
if ( $image !== false ) {
  echo '<img src="'.$image.'" width="500" />';
}

function random_image( $key = "love" ) {
  $url  = sprintf( "https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&tbm=isch&sout=1", urlencode( trim( $key ) ) );
  $html = get_page( $url );
  if ( $html ) {
    $images = find_images( $html );
    if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
      $images = $images[array_rand( $images )];
      return $images;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function get_page( $url = null ) {
  $url  = trim( $url );
  if ( !$url ) {
    return false;
  }
  return @file_get_contents( $url );
}

function find_images( $html = null ) {
  $html = trim( $html );
  if ( !$html ) {
    return false;
  }
  $html = str_get_html( $html );
  $imgs = array();
  if ( $links = $html->find( ".images_table td a" ) ) {
    foreach( $links as $link ) {
      $link = ( isset( $link->href ) ) ? $link->href : null;
      $link = htmlspecialchars_decode( parse_url( $link, PHP_URL_QUERY ) );
      parse_str( $link, $link );
      if ( isset( $link["imgurl"] ) ) {
        $imgs[] = urldecode( trim( $link["imgurl"] ) );
      }
    }
  }
  unset( $html );
  return $imgs;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, the simplest way I figured out is using google image api (for now its free to use):

```
function random_google_image($topic='') {
    $url = sprintf('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=%s&v=1.0&rsz=large&start=1', urlencode($topic));
    $results = json_decode(file_get_contents($url))->responseData->results;
    $image = $results[array_rand($results)];
    return $image->url;
}

echo random_google_image('sexy girl');
```

Api request gets first 8 images. Notice start variable in api url - you can also randomize that to get some more variability. Also check all properties of $image object, there are some information that might be useful (depending on your use case).

To get totally random image first you should define your topics, like "landscape", "image", "picture", "horizon", "house", "sky", "sea" etc. Then pass random one to above function.

Comment: this api has been deprecated, this answer unfortunately no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while ago when I couldn't get the ones above to work, I hope this helps someone. It means you don't need to include any other project (Simple HTML DOM Parser for example), you can just use the code as-is.

You will need to install DOMDocument and XML ability into PHP.

https://github.com/damiankw/google.imagesearch

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function GetRandomImageURL($topic='', $min=0, $max=100)
{
  // get random image from Google
  if ($topic=='') $topic='image';
  $ofs=mt_rand($min, $max);
  $geturl='http://www.google.ca/images?q=' . $topic . '&start=' . $ofs . '&gbv=1';
  $data=file_get_contents($geturl);
 

 //partialString1 is bigger link.. in it will be a scr for the beginning of the url
  $f1='<div class="lIMUZd"><div><table class="TxbwNb"><tr><td><a href="/url?q=';
  $pos1=strpos($data, $f1)+strlen($f1);
  $partialString1 = substr($data, $pos1);
  
  //partialString 2 starts with the URL
  $f2='src="';
  $pos2=strpos($partialString1, $f2)+strlen($f2);
  $partialString2 = substr($partialString1, $pos2, 400);
  
  //PartialString3 ends the url when it sees the "&amp;"
  $f3='&amp;';
  $urlLength=strpos($partialString2, $f3);
  $partialString3 = substr($partialString2, 0,  $urlLength);
  
  return $partialString3;

}
 
 echo GetRandomImageURL();

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This will help you

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php